# AngularJS - When does a scope created by $scope.$new() removed. Does the garbage collector or Angular takes care of it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, angularjs-scope

I am looking to know how a scope that is created by $scope.$new() is removed in  below scenario.

My Scenario - A new scope is created by $scope.$new(), some properties added to it and it is passed to a angular script template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="row-details.html">
<tr><td>code</td></tr>
</script>
```

which creates a new table row on the fly. So every `<tr>` row gets a new scope in my case. I am creating table rows on the fly whenever a row or column is double clicked in my html table.

Now on some event, say for example - 'double click' on some parent row or column or anywhere, I delete this new row which was created via template with new scope via $scope.$new(), my question is will this also delete the reference to the $scope.$new() scope or I will have to manually remove it or will at some point the garbage collector will remove it seeing that there is no reference to it since the table row which was using it, is removed from the DOM.

Overall concern for above is I want to ensure there is no memory leak in the application.

So in general I have two questions -

1. Will the new scope be removed automatically by angular or garbage collector once the relevant DOM row is removed from DOM.
2. How can I test this via Chrome Dev Tools or any other way whether the reference is removed or not and there is no memory leak for that specific code.

Please let me know if you require more details.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes. Accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope is removed when someone calls its `$destroy` method.

The scope is also removed when one of its ancestors is removed.

"Removal" implies that the scope and its children will no longer receive digest calls, and additionally, should be garbage-collected.

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) of scope of `$new` and `$destroy` methods.

> **$new(isolate, parent);**
>
> Creates a new child scope.
>
> The parent scope will propagate the `$digest()` event. The scope can be removed from the scope hierarchy using `$destroy()`.
>
> `$destroy()` must be called on a scope when it is desired for the scope and its child scopes to be permanently detached from the parent and thus stop participating in model change detection and listener notification by invoking.
>
> **$destroy();**
>
> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.

Specifically, to your question, you must call `$destroy` on the child scope you created. Just removing the DOM element would not trigger it - the child scope is still in the scope hierarchy and has references to it.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0MuoyKymibklLGWgTic0?p=preview) - for illustration